# std::vector.data(), &std::vector[0] and &std::vector.front() returning wrong values

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, std

I'm having a little issue that i don't know how to fix. I'm trying to send a `std::vector<float*>` to the GPU, and in order to do that, I have to return the elements from the array as values instead of pointers.

This `float`-pointer vector just for testing is storing 2 squares with 4 vertices each, having a total of 8 elements in the vector:

```cpp
int main()
{
    //Start up code goes here

    Model m(//position, rotation, scale);
    RendererCore::AddModel(m);

    //...
}

void RendererCore::AddModel(Model& m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m.vertices.size(); i++)
    {
        allVerts.push_back(&m.vertices[i].position.x);
        std::cout << *allVerts.back() << std::endl;

        allVerts.push_back(&m.vertices[i].position.y);
        std::cout << *allVerts.back() << std::endl;

        allVerts.push_back(&m.vertices[i].position.z);
        std::cout << *allVerts.back() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I print them after that, it seems that everything is fine!

```
-1.5
0.5
1
-1.5
-0.5
1
-0.5
-0.5
1
-0.5
0.5
1
-0.5
0.5
0
-0.5
-0.5
0
0.5
-0.5
0
0.5
0.5
0
```

But now, when I try to pass them to values like this:

```cpp
float* result = *&allVerts[0];

//Print data just to test
for(int i = 0; i < allVerts.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;
}
```

And print the elements from the "float array", it shows the wrong values!

```
-1.5
0.5
1
1
1
1
1
1
-1.5
-0.5
1
1
1
1
1
1
-0.5
-0.5
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

This also happens with `*&allVerts.front()` and `allVerts.data()`.

A workaround for this is doing a `for` loop and push the elements one by one, but probably the more models the vector will have, the more it will cost compared to passing the elements to value from the memory address (correct me if I'm wrong, maybe it takes the same amount of time?), so I want to stick with fixing the issue.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are using `AddModel()` and printing the values exactly.  BTW, `float* result = *&allVerts[0];` and `float* result = *&allVerts.front()` are the same as `float* result = allVerts[0];` But `float* result = allVerts.data()`  will not compile, as `data()` will be returning a `float**` not a `float*`.

Comment: I edited it now and i tried to provide an example, including how i printed the values. Is this alright?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that you have a vector of pointers, which don't necessarily all point to contiguous memory.  So you can't treat them as such.

In order to get your values into a contiguous array of floats, you'll need to copy them into a contiguous array of floats.  Something like

```
std::vector<float *> allVerts;
std::vector<float> copy;

copy.clear();
for (float *p : allVerts)
    copy.push_back(*p);
```

Now you can use `copy.data()` (or `&copy[0]`) to get a pointer to the contiguous array of float values.

Comment: I thought it was something i was doing wrong. Thanks for explaining man, i appreciate it :D